# Poll X events via file descriptor or socket

Tags: c, x11, epoll, unix-socket

Since X is a server, I there a way to listen for X events via a socket instead of using `XNextEvent`?

I have a program that monitors system events via `epoll` with `epoll_wait` called in a loop running in the main thread. Since I haven't been able to figure out how to listen for X events via a file descriptor, I had to resort to running a dedicated loop for `XNextEvent` in a separate thread and putting mutexes around calls to the functions that are called when events occur.

Here's the function I wrote for polling the X events, if anyone is curious. I'm only listening for events related to keyboard layout switching, at the moment.

```
void* xevent_loop(void*) {
  int xkbEventType;
  XkbQueryExtension(dpy, 0, &xkbEventType, 0, 0, 0);
  XkbSelectEventDetails(dpy,
    XkbUseCoreKbd, XkbStateNotify, XkbAllStateComponentsMask,
    XkbGroupStateMask);
  XSync(dpy, False);

  for (XEvent e;;) {
    XNextEvent(dpy, &e);
    if (e.type == xkbEventType) {
      XkbEvent* xkbe = (XkbEvent*) &e;
      if (xkbe->any.xkb_type == XkbStateNotify) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&setroot_mutex);
        fmt_kbd_layout(xkbe->state.group);
        setroot();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&setroot_mutex);
      }
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: (Warning: completely untested idea): Have one thread looping with `XPeekEvent()` to wait for events, and when there is one queued, notify the main thread (Maybe using `eventfd` or whatever else you like) that it should read queued events (`XPending()` will tell you how many there are).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the connection's file descriptor by using the macro `ConnectionNumber(dpy)` on the display. See `man ConnectionNumber`:

> The ConnectionNumber macro returns a connection number for the specified display.

This can be used in `select()` and `poll()` to check for an event being ready.
The definition is in `/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the `ConnectionNumber` macro gets the `fd` member from the display struct, which has a comment labeling it as a Network socket. When I call `read` on the socket, what should I expect to be reading? I'm probably going to get some event struct rather than human-readable text.

Comment: You shouldn't `read()` it, only `select()` or `poll()` or `epoll()` it. If it shows ready for EPOLLIN then call `XNextEvent()` to get the data. Then return to the poll loop for another event.

Comment: Gotcha. That should work. But just out of curiosity, does the socket itself not carry any information aside from event readiness?

Comment: The X11 connection socket is not special. You can use it just like any socket, but the data stream you read/write is highly structured, and quite complex. You can see some of that detail at the start of the protocol doc [pdf](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/x11proto/proto.pdf).